# SQL Error: Error mapping failed

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm having problem when I connected with database remote using TSQLDataSet, I set property `GetMetaData = False` and even then the error persists. I realized that this error ocorred when I call method recordCount.

```
if dmOS.ExecutaPesquisa('Select IDLOJA from LOJA') > 0 then
begin
  with dmOS.qryPesquisa do
  begin
    while not EOF do
    begin
      strCampos := Concat('Insert into PRODUTOFILIAL (PRO_CODIGO, LOJA_ID, ');
      strValores := Concat(' Values        (', QuotedStr(cdsProduto.FieldByName('pro_codigo').AsString), ',', FieldByName('IDLOJA').AsString, ',');
      strSQL := CriaSQLInclusao(cdsProduto, strCampos, strValores, 2);
      AtualizaDados(strSQL, False, strMensagemErro);
      Next;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TdmOS.ExecutaPesquisa(strSQLPesquisa: string): Integer;
{Esta função serve para fazer pesquisas no banco de dados, de acordo com o parâmetro SQL
 dado. Retorno: -1: Erro na execução da pesquisa, > 0:Query OK - Retorna número de registros encontrados}
begin
  Result := -1;

  qryPesquisa.Close;
  qryPesquisa.CommandText := strSQLPesquisa;
  try
    qryPesquisa.Open;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      GravaLog(Concat('Erro SQL: ', strSQLPesquisa, '-', E.Message), 'LG');
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  if qryPesquisa.IsEmpty then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := qryPesquisa.RecordCount; // Here's the error
end;
```

Comment: Why are you accessing `RecordCount` on a SQL database? You don't use the return value for anything anyway, so it could return a Boolean: `Result := not qryPesquisa.IsEmpty;`, and use it as `if dmOS.ExecutaPesquisa(...) then ...`.

Comment: i not noticed, thanks